# Spring REST service throw "406 Not Acceptable": org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm trying to create a simple REST service with Spring. Errors occur in elementary queries: 
**HTTP 406 Not Acceptable: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation**

I have a simple controller:

```
package com.test.my.rest;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/sample", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public class SampleRestController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/test_string")
    public String getString() {
        return "Hello";
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/test_string_wrap")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getEntityString() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello");
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/test_int")
    public Integer getInt() {
        return 1;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/test_int_wrap")
    public ResponseEntity<Integer> getInteger() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new Integer(2));
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/test_item")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Item>> getItems() {
        List<Item> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(new Item(1, "Item1"));
        list.add(new Item(2, "Item2"));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(list);
    }
}
```

I tried to call the services using the browser and the curl utility:

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8070/rest/sample/test_int -v
```

or

```
http://localhost:8070/rest/sample/test_int
```

But all methods (except ../test_string and ../test_string_wrap) throw this HTTP 406 error, even elementary http://localhost:8070/rest/sample/test_int:

```
[[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] TRACE org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:124 - Error handling return value=[1], type=java.lang.Integer in public java.lang.Integer com.test.my.rest.SampleRestController.getInt()
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:306) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:180) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:119) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [javax.servlet.javax.servlet-api.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [javax.servlet.javax.servlet-api.jar:3.1.0]
```

My configuration **web.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.my.config.SpringContextConfig</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.test.my.config.SpringDispatcherConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>99</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Configuration **SpringDispatcherConfig**:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test.my.rest"})
public class SpringDispatcherConfig {
}
```

Configuration **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
...
  <properties>
        <spring.version>5.1.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jackson.version>2.9.8</jackson.version>
        <jxls.version>2.5.1</jxls.version>
        <jxls-poi.version>1.1.0</jxls-poi.version>
    </properties>
...
 <dependencies>
...
   <dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
...
     </dependencies>
</project>
```

Configuration for weblogic 12.2.1 **weblogic.xml**:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app.xsd"
                                    xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app">

    <context-root>/</context-root>
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
        <prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
            <package-name>com.fasterxml.*</package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>
    </container-descriptor>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

Please help to understand what is wrong :(

Comment: `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE` is not equal to `application/json`. Did you try setting the `ACCEPT` header to `application/json;charset=UTF-8` ? I don't know if Spring should be resolving this on its own though

Comment: yes, I tried to invoke as "curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8" http://localhost:8070/rest/sample/test_int -v" but result is same: HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable

Comment: can you show me the headers while requesting this api "/test_int"?

Comment: Does test_string work? If yes it the reason might be the return value? So something is wrong with jackson?

Comment: Headers:  > GET /rest/sample/test_int HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9999
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: application/json
>
< HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
< Date: Thu, 28 Mar 2019 08:56:50 GMT
< Content-Length: 0

Comment: Yes, ../test_string is work, I  also do not understand what can be reason in jakson :(

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web/5.1.3.RELEASE

com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat » jackson-dataformat-cbor (optional) 2.9.7 

Maybe too high version of Jackson?

Comment: Tried with <jackson.version>2.9.7</jackson.version>, the problem is remained

Comment: This is what spring boot is adding, maybe you need somthng

com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.9.8:compile
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.9.8:compile
com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.9.8:compile
 com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.9.8:compile
com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.9.8:compile

Comment: Ttried with the libraries you specified, did not help. May be something with configuratuon app server? I ues Weblogic 12.2.1 and additionaly use weblogic xml with config: `<context-root>/</context-root>
 <container-descriptor>
  <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
  <prefer-application-packages>
   <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
   <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
   <package-name>com.fasterxml.*</package-name>
  </prefer-application-packages>
 </container-descriptor>`

Answer (score 1):

After thousands trial, hours and errors I found a solution to the problem.

Jackson converters are not not pulled up to AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor constructor in List> converters...

Because ... should have added an annotation @EnableWebMvc at SpringDispatcherConfig/

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc  // solve the problem
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.bpcbt.iplan.rest"})
public class SpringDispatcherConfig {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting your header's accept-type for all your API requests. Currently, I'm setting '*locally*' ( for only one of your APIs) but you can set it '*globally*'.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/test_int_wrap")
public ResponseEntity<Integer> getInteger() {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)); try setting this media type.

    return ResponseEntity
          .ok(new Integer(2))
          .headers(responseHeaders);
}
```

Comment: @Sora Let me know here, if it worked for you or not?

Comment: Your API is not supported by my spring version. Try to as:   `MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.put(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));
  return new ResponseEntity(new Integer(2), headers, HttpStatus.OK);` But error is remained.

Comment: make MediaType to APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE instead of APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE in your above comment, and look if it works.

Comment: Done and tried with `curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8" http://localhost:9999/rest/sample/test_int -v` and `curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:9999/rest/sample/test_int -v`.It didn't help :(

Comment: This is just another way to use spring. The problem is jackson i guess.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation